# Formal grammar description for SCSS and LESS

Tags: editor, sass, phped

There's a forum request for the IDE PhpED to provide syntax support for SCSS and possibly LESS. The response from the PhpED folks has been that they are not able to find a formal description of the grammar similar to the CSS grammar described here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html

Does anyone know where a formal description can be found? There are lot of PhpED users (including me) who would like SCSS support.

Comment: You would be better off contacting the developers of LESS and SASS.

Comment: Although they are pretty well crafted, I don't think there's a standard specifications document like CSS for them. Have a look at this file from jsass. https://code.google.com/p/jsass/source/browse/trunk/src/org/lucubrate/jsass/Sass.g

Comment: I am also using PhpED but I'm moving to phpStorm. PhpED doesn't support too many things right now. Developers say - there is no formal grammar but in fact it's only excuse in my opinion - there is SASS/SCSS/LESS support in other editors like phpStorm (with Compass support too) or SublimeText editor and their developers managed somehow to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that phpEd will support SCSS soon (in version 14) so developers managed to find grammar. But there is no info about LESS or SASS syntax.